# probability distribution for the discrete random variable- 2 unknowns

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Fill in the
values in the table below to give a legitimate probability distribution for the discrete random variable "X".
, whose possible values are -5, -3 ,-2, 3 and 5.

Value of x of X: P(X=x)

```
 -5        :   0.11
 -3        :   0.12
 -2        :   0.30
  3        :    ?
  5        :    ?
```

I tried

0.11+0.12+0.30+X1+X2=1

But i can't find the answer

Comment: You might be confused by the fact that more answers are possible. Just choose one.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: You are asked to fill in values such that there is legitimate probability distribution for a discrete rv... etc. Well, that's done if e.g. you fill in the numbers $0.27$ and $0.20$. Let both be positive and let their sum be $0.47=1-0.11-0.12-0.30$.

Comment: so that means, we can put any number we want, as long as it adds up to 1

Comment: Not any of course (e.g. probabilities do not exceed $1$), but there are indeed lots of choices that induce a "legimate probability distribution". I cannot think of any other interpretation.

Comment: ohh I get it. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).